# How to stop gVim wrapping text at column 80

Tags: gvim, split, wrapping

I have a `README.txt` file as follows:

```
This document is a list of
a) Known issues in the services or test environment, i.e. things expected to fail
b) Things to be improved in the test suite
c) Possible bugs to be followed up
```

If I add anything to line 2, gVim automagically wraps it as follows

```
a) Known issues in the services or test environment, i.e. things expected to
fail blahblah
```

This is super annoying. 
I am running gVim on Windows, with the plugins "solarized" and "airline". I have tried to tame this behaviour with the following in my `vimrc`: (to no avail)

```
set nowrap              " don't wrap by default
set tw=0                " don't jump to newline after col 80
```

It only seems to happen with a `.txt` file, others are OK.

Comment: Inside the README file check the output of `:verbose set tw?` and `:verbose set fo?`.

Comment: Output from tw: `textwidth=78 Last set from C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim`
Output from fo: `formatoptions=tcq Last set from C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim`

Comment: Commented out the offending line of `vimrc_example.vim`. Problem fixed, thanks

Comment: Interestingly, all three of the answers below have useful and insightful information into why this setting might be behaving as such.  I almost wish there was a 'extended accepted answer' reward that could be given in such situations.

Comment: Agreed, I have upvoted all of the answers but can only choose one 'accepted' answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try turning off automatic formatting:

```
set formatoptions=
```

If this works, you're going to want to try to track down how it's having an effect. There are two possibilities. Either you have `'wrapmargin'` set (which causes Vim to insert newlines when you get within a certain distance of the edge of the window), or something is setting `'textwidth'` after your `.vimrc` has been read. Use `:verbose set wrapmargin?` and `:verbose set textwidth?` to find out their values and what set them.

It's also possible that something is overriding your `'wrap'` setting, causing the lines to *display* on several screen-lines, but you'd probably know if this were the case, because the wrapping would occur at the end of the window. Using the `'ruler'` or `'showbreak'` settings make this sort of wrapping easier to see.

#### UPDATE:

It turns out that the `textwidth` was set by an autocommand created in a file `vimrc_example.vim` in the Vim installation, which was being loaded at startup by the line `source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim` in the OP's `.vimrc`.

Other answerers have suggested editing the example file, or overriding the autocommand with further autocommands, but a cleaner solution would be to edit your .vimrc *not* to source the example file. If the example contains some settings you *do* want, these can be copied into your own .vimrc.

Comment: Thanks, `set formatoptions=` fixed the behaviour. From my comment above it looks like gvim is taking settings from `vimrc_example.vim` so I'll rename the file to `vimrc_example.vimx` and see what happens

Comment: PS: Vim 7.4 has default `.vimrc` that includes `vimrc_example.vim` which sets `textwidth=78`

Comment: The default gVim vimrc is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`, which sources `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim` (probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimXY\vimrc_example.vim`, where XY is your vim version).

Answer (score 6):

As per Kenny Evitt's answer, you can find where textwidth is being set using verbose:

```
:verbose set tw?
  textwidth=78
    Last set from c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim
```

If you are happy editing that file, do so.

If you would prefer not to edit whichever file (or cannot), then you can override it in your own .vimrc (or _vimrc) file.

If it not being set via an autocmd, you can simply undo it.

```
set textwidth=0
```

If it is an autocmd, then it won't be set until you open the .txt file (or whatever) and simply setting textwidth=0 in your own .vimrc file won't do anything because it will be overridden.

Therefore, you need to prevent or override the autocmd.

To my way of thinking, you ought to be able to undo the autocmd using something like

```
autocmd! FileType text set textwidth=78
```

For me, that doesn't work in .vimrc. It does work if you give it manually once vim has started, but that's not so much use. This feels like a bug in vim, but maybe there's a good reason for it.

What does work for me is to add this to my .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType text set textwidth=0
```

Comment: Your `:autocmd!` will replace all *existing* autocommands for the `FileType text` event with your `set textwidth 78` command. Is the `78` a typo, or is that really the command you were trying to use?

Comment: A better way of removing only the specific autocommand you don't like would be with with the command: `autocmd! vimrcEx FileType text`, which will only remove the FileType autocommands in the `vimrcEx` group. (i.e. just the autocommand you don't want). Be sure that this line occurs *after* the line where you source the example vimrc file.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, [Vitor's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/how-to-stop-gvim-wrapping-text-at-column-80/2786#comment2888_2784) suggested I run the following:

```
:verbose set tw?
```

Doing so gave me the following output:

```
textwidth=78
      Last set from C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim
```

In *vimrc_example.vim*, I found the relevant lines:

```
" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  ...

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  ...
```

And I found that my *.vimrc* is sourcing that file:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

In my case, I don't want `textwidth` to be set for any files, so I just commented out the relevant line in *vimrc_example.vim*.